# CFPreferences Background Sync Queue Crashed

Tags: ios, crash, core-foundation, cfpreferences

I have integrated crashlytics to track the crashes in my ios application. The application got crashed and the stack trace does not point in the application and this crash is inconsistent, could not reproduced. Could anyone has an idea why it is having an issue.
[image: Crashlytics stack trace]

Comment: I see this crash a lot in crashlytics too. Haven't been able to figure out a cause though since it happens in lot of different places and even in 3rd party SDK's we use.

Answer (score 0):

That crash occurred while converting the objects stored in preferences into a property list. It's likely that one of them was over-released or otherwise corrupted after being stored.